# SQLAlchemy pool.addListener Error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm creating a pylons app and I keep getting an error when trying to start the app with paster. I've searched for answers on google and keep coming up with nothing. Anyone have any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/opt/python2.7/bin/paster", line 8, in <module>  
load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.3', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 84, in run  
invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 123, in invoke  
exit_code = runner.run(args)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 218, in run  
result = self.command()  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/paste/script/serve.py", line 276, in command  
relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.7.egg/paste/script/serve.py", line 313, in loadapp  
**kw)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 203, in loadapp  
return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 224, in loadobj  
return context.create()  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 617, in create  
return self.object_type.invoke(self)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 109, in invoke  
return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/util/fixtypeerror.py", line 57, in fix_call  
val = callable(*args, **kw)  
File "/home/tripwire/foo.com/foo/foo/config/middleware.py", line 37, in make_app  
config = load_environment(global_conf, app_conf)  
File "/home/tripwire/foo.com/foo/foo/config/environment.py", line 49, in load_environment  
engine = engine_from_config(config, 'sqlalchemy.')  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 281, in engine_from_config  
return create_engine(url, **opts)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 263, in create_engine  
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)  
File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.6-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 152, in create  
pool.add_listener({'first_connect':first_connect})  
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_listener'
```

Comment: Some more info (and code) would be nice. Can you successfully use your SQLAlchemy business code outside of paster?

Comment: I'm pretty new to pylons so I'm not really sure. I'll look up how to use that code outside of paster and give it a try. Other than that I don't know what code/info would be helpful the error looks like it's coming from SQLAlchemy itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the book i was using said to use
    sqlalchemy.pool = 3600
But apparently it's supposed to be
    sqlalchemy.pool_recycle = 3600